# do you know why useEffect execute everytimes i enter input?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

do you why useEffect execute every times i type a letter at input?

I don't think the input will affect 'useEffect'...

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const DBLab = () => {
    const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");

    const printfunc = () => {
        console.log("print");
    }
    useEffect(()=> {
        const print = () => {
            printfunc();
        } 
        print();
    },[printfunc]);
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>dblab</h1>
            <h1>{hashHistory}</h1>
            <input type='text' value={inputValue} onChange={(e)=>setInputValue(e.target.value)}/>
        </div>
    )
}

export default DBLab;
```

Comment: Because `printfunc` is redeclared every render cycle. When the `inputValue` state is updated a rerender is triggered. Either move `printfunc` ***into*** the `useEffect` callback body, or memoize `printfunc` with `useMemo` or `useCallback` hooks.

Comment: @DrewReese thanks... do you know how to not redeclared every render cycle?

Comment: Yes, I explained that in the second half of my comment. The code in your question seems an overly simple/trivial example and I suspect you've a specific issue. Can you update your question to include your real code (*if this is the case*)?

Comment: As per the [official documentation's "FAQ"](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks). `useEffect` is triggered _every time_ `render()` runs. If you don't want that, also as per the docs: [customize that behaviour](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects).

Comment: I see. Well, cheers and good luck friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you enter a letter you update the `inputValue` which causes the component to re-render. When the component re-renders, the variable `printfunc` is re-initialised. And because your `useEffect` function has `printfunc` in the dependency array it is triggered each time this variable changes.

To solve this, remove `printfunc` from the array like so:

```js
    useEffect(()=> {
        const print = () => {
            printfunc();
        } 
        print();
    },[]);
```